# Changing Read-Only on folder with Powershell - Greyed out

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to remove or change the Read Only attribute on a folder with **`Powershell`**, **`Windows server 2008 R2`**. I'm really struggling with this issue. 
I have even tried **`attrib.exe`**, but the greyd out mark will not disappear in "Folder Properties".
 Have anyone had the same issue? Whatever I do it is still greyed out.

The Read Only property on the folder is grey, however, the files inside the folder are not read-only. Strange.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this is a UI "bug", clearing the checkbox will not fix it, even with command line.

See this KB, none of the mentioned workarounds worked for me.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326549

Comment: So it is a bug. It makes sense.

Comment: Indeed. See [this MSKB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326549) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the workarounds without any success as well.

Comment: Consider marking this as the answer if it answered your question

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my problem was I needed to remove the read-only attribute of the sub-files inside the directory.  I was then able to do something with the parent directory (in my case remove it):

```
dir -r $PrePackageDirectory |% {if ($_.PSIsContainer -ne $true){$_.IsReadOnly = $false}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem on a Windows 10 machine where a folder from the previous OS was marked readonly.  I used `attrib -r c:\FolderName` from a powershell prompt to remove the attribute.  Note there is no trailing slash on the folder name.  This is from the KB article but powershell tab+autocomplete includes the trailing slash and the command did not work for me.